# Kotlin - reflection and type safety

Tags: kotlin, reflection, type-safety

I am writing a small library for programatically generating SQL queries.
The goal is that the API of this library can be used like that:

```kotlin
myQuery.where(
    MyClass::id equal "foo",
    MyClass::age notEqual 55 
).findAll()
```

The signatures of both the `where` function, and the infix operators is under my control. Here are the relevant definitions that I have at the moment:

```kotlin
interface KpaFilter<BASE, FIELD>

infix fun <BASE: Any, FIELD: Any> KProperty1<BASE, FIELD>.equal(value: FIELD): KpaFilter<BASE, FIELD> { ... }

fun <BASE: Any> where(vararg filters: KpaFilter<BASE, *>?): KpaQuery<BASE>
```

Still, I cannot find a proper way to make this type safe. For example, I would like this to raise a compilation error, but unfortunately, it compiles:

```kotlin
val someFilter = MyClass::id equal 55 // id is a string
```

Is it possible to somehow modify the signatures of the declarations above and achieve this kind of type safety, without making the API more cumbersome than its current form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using Kotlin internal APIs, there is a hidden feature in the compiler which does exactly this. The feature is enabled by annotating a parameter with `@kotlin.internal.Exact`:

```kotlin
@Suppress("INVISIBLE_REFERENCE", "INVISIBLE_MEMBER")
infix fun <BASE: Any, FIELD: Any> KProperty1<BASE, @kotlin.internal.Exact FIELD>.equal(value: FIELD): KpaFilter<BASE, FIELD> { ... }
```

This works pretty well and can be used in regular Kotlin projects. Of course, we don't have guarantees it will be supported in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! Yes it works perfect. Still, I hope there is some "official" way to achieve this. If none is found, I will mark this as accepted answer.